# ArrayListAdapter - ListView animations

Tags: android, listview, animation

How can I create animations correctly (in listview)?

I have this code:

```
public void blink(final View v)
{
    final Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
    animation.setDuration(500);
    animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);

    v.startAnimation(animation);

    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try { Thread.sleep(2000); }
            catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

            v.clearAnimation();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

And View is animated in "getView" function (ArrayListAdapter):

```
if(!alarm.isAnimated())
{
    blink(view);
    alarm.setAnimated(true);
}
```

This works pretty good, but I need to update view very often and every update cancels my animation ...

```
notifyDataSetChanged(); // calls getView, isAnimated = true, animation is canceled
```

And also I don't want to just reset the animation (it may end in the middle and it would not look good) and I also want to animate only when I add item into list view (not when updating)...

Thanks for help.

EDIT:

The entire adapter:

```
public class AlertListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AlarmEntity>
{
    private ArrayList<AlarmEntity> data;

    public AlertListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<AlarmEntity> data)
    {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, data);
        this.data = (data);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        @SuppressLint("ViewHolder") View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_row, parent, false);

        return getView(getItem(position), view);
    }

    private View getView(AlarmEntity alarm, View view)
    {
        if(!alarm.isAnimated())
        {
            blink(view);
            alarm.setAnimated(true);
        }

        return (view);
    }

    public void update()
    {
        for(AlarmEntity e : data)
            e.setDistance(Coords.getDistance(CarEntity.location, e.getLocation()));

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void blink(final View v)
    {
        final Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
        animation.setDuration(500);
        animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);

        v.startAnimation(animation);

        new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try { Thread.sleep(2000); }
                catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

                v.clearAnimation();
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code of your adapter

Comment: Done, if it helps you (but i Wrote everything) - I'm calling just adapter.update();

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is not to use long-duration animations to add cell into ListView. :-D

```
public void pushIn(final View v)
{
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.getContext(), R.anim.push_left_anim);
    animation.setDuration(500);
    v.startAnimation(animation);
}
```

It's looking better than blinking :-D

```
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0"
         android:duration="300"/>
   <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
         android:duration="300" />
</set>
```